# Clicking on one of the widgets in the QListWidgetItem and accessing another widget in the same item in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

I wrote a UI with PyQt5 and
I used a qlistwidget that has 10 QListWidgetItem
And each QListWidgetItem contains a button and a label

The help I want consists of three parts:

part1:What I want is to be able to click on the button in each QListWidgetItem to access the label in the same item.
For example, when I click on button2, label2 will be printed, or when I click on button8, label8 will be printed.

Also, by clicking on each item in qListWidget, the label in that item can be printed
For example, by clicking on the third item in qListWidget, the label in the third item will be printed

part2:I want to create a space between each label and button
It means that the label should be placed on the left side of each item and the button should be placed on the right side of each item

part3:When the program is executed, a loop will be set on all the items in QListWidget and the label in each item will be printed

this is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *




class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400 , 600)

        menu_widget = QListWidget()
        menu_widget.setStyleSheet('''
            QListWidget {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #33373B;
            }

           QListWidget::item {
           height: 50px;
           }

            QListWidget::item:selected {
           background-color: #2ABf9E;
           }
            ''')
        for i in range(1,11):
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            widget = QWidget()
            widgetText =  QLabel(f"label {i}")
            widgetButton =  QPushButton(f"button {i}")
            widgetButton.setMinimumHeight(10) 
            widgetLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
            widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetButton)
            widgetLayout.addStretch()
            widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)  
            #item.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint()) 
            #item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            #widgetLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 10)
            menu_widget.addItem(item)
            menu_widget.setItemWidget(item , widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(menu_widget)

        self.setLayout(layout)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    w = Widget()
    w.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please be aware that you may only ask one specific question per post, not *many broad* questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1, use:

```
from functools import partial
def print_label(label):
    print(label.text())

for i in range(1, 11):
    widgetText =  QLabel(f"label {i}")
    widgetButton =  QPushButton(f"button {i}")
    widgetButton.clicked.connect(partial(print_label, widgetText))
    ...
```

Buttons will be connected with a partial function, a function preloaded with the right label object on each iteration, then accessible on print_label.

For part 2, simply use the .addStretch() between the 2 .addWidget(), should work fine!

Comment: Thanks, it works fine for the buttons, but when I try to do the same for the items, I get this error --> 'QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'clicked'
How can I do the same for each item?

Also, I added a third part to my question. Please help me with the third part

Comment: There is currentRowChanged signal from the QListWidget.
You should subclass QListWidgetItem and use currentItemChanged, having a custom list item will be easier for all the rest.
What is the use case for part 3 ? Use a QTimer to run a method each xxx seconds, iterate over items then print the labels.